# How can I convert a date and time from UTC to EST in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a date (coming from Twitter statistics) that's coming in the following format:

`2017-07-25 03:55 +0000`

I need to convert the date and time so that it more accurately reflects when the post was actually made. So I just need to subtract 5 hours (I don't care about whether it's daylight savings or not), but I need to make sure that the date changes if the date for EST is different than it would be in UTC.

So, in that example time above, I would get back '2017-07-24 10:55'

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible

First, change your time string to a time format that Google Sheets can understand. In a new cell (like B2):

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A2, 1, 10)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A2, 12, 5))
```

This formula separates your time string into a date and a time, then changes them into GoogleSheets date and time.

Next, subtract 5 hours from this time. In another new cell (like C2), use this:

```
 =B2 - TIME(5, 0, 0)
```

This formula takes away 5 hours from the original time.

If you want to change how the time looks, you can choose the cell, then click on "Format" > "Number" > "Custom time" in the menu, then put in the format you want, like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm".

This method doesn't think about daylight savings .